# How to make horizontal scroll on bootstrap grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I'm Bootstrap beginner.

I want to make horizontal scroll when content overflow their parent div's width.

If i give static width value to parent  it work well..

but when i give dynamic width (like col-xs, col-md) it doesn't work..

[ HTML ]

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color:green">other contents</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color:pink; overflow-x:auto;">
          <h4>scrollable horizontal</h4>
          <div class='content'>something...</div>
          <div class='content'>something...</div>
          <div class='content'>something...</div>
          <div class='content'>something...</div>
          <div class='content'>something...</div>
          <div class='content'>something...</div>      
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"  style="background-color:orange;">ohter contents</div>
    </div>
```

[ CSS ]

```
.content{
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0px 5px;
}

h4 {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/m9gauc63/1/

In JSFiddle, I want make horizontal scrollbar in pink  area so 
 arranged horizontally.

thanks alot!

Comment: sorry guy.. it's my misundertand of css..

add [white-space:nowrap] in content class css.

it work fine

Answer (score 0):

I an not sure.Please try

```
.content{
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0px 5px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

h4 {
  text-align:center;
}
```